# JHipster: Why node_modules and other front-end files got generated for --skip-client flag?

Tags: jhipster

I created a new JHipster project with the following command:

```
jhipster --skip-client
```

Since, I skipped client generation via `--skip-client`, why the newly created project contains the following files and folders which I think are related to frontend and not related to backend anywhere:

- node_modules
- package.json
- .yo-rc.json
- yarn.lock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [link](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7585), it seems like it is actually a feature and not a bug.

The purpose of installing a local copy of `generator-jhipster` is that if you upgrade your global version, the local version will still match what your project uses. This protects you from using a newer entity generator on an older project. You can skip the installation of the local `generator-jhipster` by using `--skip-install` (note that your project will then always use the global `generator-jhipster`)

The `.yo-rc.json` file has the answers to your prompt and other details about your project that help with the other subgenerators such as `entity` or `import-jdl`. This file is important to keep.